# g_io_channel + socket = client, and GIO not work properly

Tags: c, sockets, glib, gio

dude here im gonna create client and combine with GIO Channel, and after i put it all together, it seems appears to work on socket, but the g_io_channel not as watching, like crashing or such..

please see following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gio/gio.h> // g_timeout_add
#include <gtk/gtk.h> // gtk 
#include <netinet/in.h> //sockaddr_in
#include <sys/socket.h> // socket();
#include <arpa/inet.h> // inet_addr();
#include <string.h> // memset();


struct dada
{
    gint id_sock;
    guint id_gio_watch;
};




gboolean incoming(GIOChannel *chan, GIOCondition condition, struct dada *didi )
{
    int byte;

    int insock = g_io_channel_unix_get_fd(chan);

    #define MAXMAX 128
    char buff[128];

    printf("sock : %d\n",insock);

    byte = recv(insock,buff,MAXMAX-1,0);

    if(byte <= 0)
    {
        perror("recv");
        close(didi->id_sock);
        g_source_remove(didi->id_gio_watch);
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        buff[byte] = '\0';
        printf("coming : %s",buff);
    }

    return TRUE;
}


// gtk area

void hello(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    g_print("Haii world  %s\n", (char *)data);

}


gint delete_event(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data)
{
    g_print("a delete event has been occured properly :D\n");

    return(0);  
}

void destroy(GtkWidget * widget, gpointer data)
{
    gtk_main_quit();  
}
// end of gtk area



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    //gtk bussines from here
      GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *button;

     gtk_init(&argc,&argv);
     window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT(window), "delete_event", GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(delete_event), NULL);
    gtk_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT(window), "destroy", GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(destroy), NULL);
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window),10);

    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("ohayo");

    gtk_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT(button), "clicked", GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(hello), (gpointer)"hha" );
    gtk_signal_connect_object(GTK_OBJECT(button), "clicked", GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(gtk_widget_destroy), GTK_OBJECT(window));

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),button);

    gtk_widget_show(button);
    gtk_widget_show(window);

    //gtk bussiness done here...


    // network code //
    struct dada didi;
    memset(&didi,0,sizeof(didi));

    struct sockaddr_in my; // set my network device info
    gint rootsock;         // handle the root socket

    //socket
    rootsock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);

    //binding
    memset(&my,0,sizeof(my));
    my.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    my.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    my.sin_port        = htons(1111);
    //bind(rootsock,(struct sockaddr*)&my,sizeof(my));

    printf("sock : %d\n",rootsock);
    connect(rootsock,(struct sockaddr*)&my,sizeof(my));

    didi.id_sock = rootsock;
    didi.id_gio_watch = g_io_add_watch(g_io_channel_unix_new(didi.id_sock),G_IO_IN|G_IO_OUT,(GIOFunc)incoming,&didi);

    // network code //

     gtk_main();





    return 0;






}
```

compiling :

```
$ gcc -o konek_gioglib konek_gioglib.c `pkg-config glib-2.0 --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0`
```

my own pc run as server with port 1111 and stream connection ( TCP ) :

```
$ nc -v -l 1111
```

running my app :

```
$ ./konek_gioglib
sock : 6
sock : 6
```

server got connection and send some word :

```
$ nc -v -l 1111
Connection from 127.0.0.1 port 1111 [tcp/*] accepted
a
a
```

and when the server send something, gtk window show but with error like these :

[image]

is there anyone dont mind to explain, why these things could happened to mine ?

Comment: gtk crashed ( error ) while the socket work, you might have not try to run these code on your machine..

Comment: is there anyone out there could help me please ? or perhaps i have to learn threading in gtk to get these thing done -_-'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well last night I brainstormed myself with my own heart, and finally could make these thing work,

here the proper code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gio/gio.h> // g_timeout_add
#include <gtk/gtk.h> // gtk
#include <netinet/in.h> //sockaddr_in
#include <sys/socket.h> // socket();
#include <arpa/inet.h> // inet_addr();
#include <string.h> // memset();
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct dada
{
    gint id_sock;
    guint id_gio_connect;
    guint id_gio_watch;
};


gboolean readdata(GIOChannel *chan,GIOCondition condition, struct dada *didi)
{

  gchar dada[20] = {0};
  int dadaz =0;


 if( condition != G_IO_IN )
    return FALSE;



  if(dadaz = recv(g_io_channel_unix_get_fd(chan),dada,19,0)<=0)
  {
      perror("recv");
      close(didi->id_sock);
      g_source_remove(didi->id_gio_connect);
      g_source_remove(didi->id_gio_watch);
      exit(0);
      return FALSE;
  }

      printf("data in : %s\n",dada);




         return TRUE;
}


gboolean incoming(GIOChannel *chan, GIOCondition condition, struct dada *didi )
{


     if( condition & G_IO_ERR || condition & G_IO_HUP )
     return FALSE;


    didi->id_gio_watch = g_io_add_watch(chan,G_IO_IN | G_IO_ERR | G_IO_HUP,(GIOFunc)readdata,didi);


    return FALSE;
}


// gtk area

void hello(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    g_print("Haii world  %s\n", (char *)data);

}


gint delete_event(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data)
{
    g_print("a delete event has been occured properly :D\n");

    return(0);
}

void destroy(GtkWidget * widget, gpointer data)
{
    gtk_main_quit();
}
// end of gtk area



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    //gtk bussines from here
      GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *button;

     gtk_init(&argc,&argv);
     window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT(window), "delete_event", GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(delete_event), NULL);
    gtk_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT(window), "destroy", GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(destroy), NULL);
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window),10);

    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("ohayo");

    gtk_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT(button), "clicked", GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(hello), (gpointer)"hha" );
    gtk_signal_connect_object(GTK_OBJECT(button), "clicked", GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(gtk_widget_destroy), GTK_OBJECT(window));

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),button);

    gtk_widget_show(button);
    gtk_widget_show(window);

    //gtk bussiness done here...


    // network code //
    struct dada didi;
    memset(&didi,0,sizeof(didi));

    struct sockaddr_in  your; // set my network device info
    gint rootsock;         // handle the root socket

    //socket
    rootsock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);



    memset(&your,0,sizeof(your));


    printf("sock : %d\n",rootsock);

    your.sin_family = AF_INET;
    your.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    your.sin_port   =   htons(1111);

    connect(rootsock,(struct sockaddr*)&your,sizeof(your));

    didi.id_sock = rootsock;
    didi.id_gio_connect = g_io_add_watch(g_io_channel_unix_new(didi.id_sock),G_IO_IN | G_IO_OUT | G_IO_ERR | G_IO_HUP,(GIOFunc)incoming,&didi);

    // network code //

     gtk_main();





    return 0;






}
```

and the only different had made is the "worked" code , need :

```
- gio for connecting, and gio for watching
```

instead of be "non-worked" code ( `only gio for connecting` ), but again i just wondering "why", why on connect() need two gio (recursively) in order make these "gio things" work,

these is really odd, if I see back then on [g_io_channel + socket = server , still just get one client ? in C language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206599/g-io-channel-socket-server-still-just-get-one-client-in-c-language)

which on accept() just need only one gio and only for watching.

if someone could explain these, how great it'll be :)